# Grep log within a time range

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I want to grep log between `13:27:45` - `13:28:00`,
I managed to grep log between `13:27` - `13:28` with the command `grep '^13:2[7-8] logfilename`, but how can I grep `13:27:45` - `13:28:00`?

Would you recommend using `sed` or even `awk` for such operation?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697958/how-to-search-for-lines-in-a-file-between-two-timestamps-using-bash) answer your question?

Comment: I think this question is about programming or software development. There is a `grep` example with a regex in the question and it has a grep tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the format `13:27:45` - `13:28:00`

```
grep "^13:\(27:\(4[5-9]\|5[0-9]\)\|28:00\)" file
```

Or

```
grep -E "^13:(27:(4[5-9]|5[0-9])|28:00)" file
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `13:` Match literally
- `(` Start a group for the alternatioms

  - `27:` Match literally
  - `(4[5-9]|5[0-9])` Match 45 - 49 or 50 - 59
  - `|` Or
  - `28:00` Match literally
- `)` Close the group

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks, I have voted to reopen it because I think the closing reason is not correct.